# Deploy IIS localhost page

Tags: .net, iis

I want to publish my Razor Pages app via IIS and I did all configuration on IIS Manager and the result is like that: I can't see my homepage, there is no page as you can see. How can I fixed that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiW76.png)

Comment: This is no published site, this is just your project folder - somehow you're pointing to the wrong folder and/or you did something incorrect.

Comment: I changed folder location with a correct one. And the result is 

This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: 1. Disable directory browsing. 2. If you hit a 500 error page, edit the question to include a full screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to deploy the razor pages on iis server:

1. Right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and select Publish.
2. In the Pick a publish target dialog, select the Folder publish option.
3. Set the Folder, Select the Publish button.
4. Download and install asp.net core hosting bundle

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-7.0.1-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

5. Open iis create website, point the folder location to the visual studio published location
6. Set the application pool to the no managed code

Comment: I did all steps and now result is 
This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: could you please enable detailed error in is and share the snapshot with us?

Comment: This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://localhost:10080/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_PORT

Comment: @CerenSusuz are you using azure vm? if yes then add the port number 10080 in the inbound firewall rule also do the same for the windows firewall